# How to find points of the x axis corresponding to the values of y equal to some value

Tags: python, numpy

I have a sine signal defined by two lists

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdWDh.png)

and I want to know the points of conductance (s) at which the voltage is 0.5.

I did it wit this code:
`voltage = [...] conductance = [...] edges = []  for n in voltage: if n == 0:  pass elif voltage[n] > 0.5 and voltage[n-1] < 0.5 : edges.append(conductance[n]) elif voltage[n] < 0.5 and voltage[n-1] > -35. : edges.append(conductance[n])'`

Is there a better or more precise way of doing it? Maybe using some numpy function? Or by intersecating with a horizontal line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sine signal appears noisy, as if you have collected it from a real source with some natural error.  One way to find the value would be to interpolate linearly between the two nearest points, assuming your test point did not fall precisely on a real point (which is unlikely in practice).  Another option would be to fit a sine wave to your noisy data and use the resulting function to generate the data you want.

Comment: Thank you. For the second option, it's not what I am searching: I want a generalizable method, which I could use also for signals of neuronal spikes.

Comment: The first suggestion is interesting, but can you explain what do you mean by interpolate linearly? Thanls

Comment: If you have two points it is relatively easy to linearly interpolate between them using the y=mx + b function for a line.  See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation.  It is also possible to fit a line or curve to more points if desired.  But for your case linear interpolation between the two nearest points to your candidate point sounds like it is what you are looking for.